# composed command as timeout parameter in bash

Tags: bash

I can use timeout as:

```
timeout 5s sleep 6s
```

But how can I pass to timeout more complex command? I've tried following but all gives me error:

```
timeout 5s sleep 6s && echo "You did not fit in timeout"
timeout 5s 'sleep 6s && echo "You did not fit in timeout"'
timeout 5s {sleep 6s && echo "You did not fit in timeout"}
timeout 5s (sleep 6s && echo "You did not fit in timeout")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
$ timeout 5 sleep 2 && echo OK || echo "You did not fit in timeout"
OK
$ timeout 1 sleep 2 && echo OK || echo "You did not fit in timeout"
You did not fit in timeout
```

Comment: Why your && is understand by sleep and mine is not?

Comment: @WakanTanka: The `&&` and `||` are interpreted by the interactive shell: If `timeout` returns 0, the `&&` part fires, otherwise the `||` part is executed. `timeout`'s exit code will be 0 if the command terminates before timeout is expired, and 124 otherwise, see manpage `timeout(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost immediately after posting I figured it out:

```
timeout 5s sh -c 'sleep 6s && echo "You did not fit in timeout"'
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: This solution is wrong because it will print `You did not fit in timeout` only if the command _was_ terminated before the timeout expires.

Comment: I know :) I was playing with timeout timer to figure out how it works, this is not to suppose do anything I was just wondering about syntax.

Comment: Now I just tried my first example `timeout 5s sleep 6s && echo "You did not fit in timeout"` and it worked. I thought it is not. The question was aimed at this problem.

Comment: We seem to have different views of the problem - which is a good thing :-) I just hope I could help. I think of it like that: The `&&` operator fires on exit code `0` (which means timeout not expired) and the `||` operator fires on anything else (timeout expired).

Comment: and if you put the `&&` inside the `sh -c` invocation, it will only check `sleep`'s exit code instead of `timeout`'s exit code, so the `&&` will always fire, unless `sh` is killed by `timeout` first.